# How to add another parameter to an existing method

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters, addition

I have a category `NSObject+Utilities` which contains all kinds of tool methods I use in my projects. Unfortunately I have to add one more parameter to a method that returns `NSColor`.

Here an Example:

```
- (NSColor*) ccBlueLight   { 
   return  [self libMakeAColor    :0.000f :0.535f :1.0f :1.000f];
}
```

The last parameter (`1.000f`) is responsible is for transparency. When I created this method I didn´t think of transparency and I fixed it to `1.000f`. Since I´m using these `cc` Colors in different projects I cannot simply add another parameter without getting errors in the other projects when using them.

Is there a way to add the transparency parameter without problems?

Comment: So let me get this straight: You want to add a parameter to a method... Without declaring any other methods?

Comment: Why don't simply create another method named `ccBlueLightWithAlpha:` that takes the alpha argument in?

Comment: Then trampoline from one to the other?

Comment: Yes, I want that the parameter is only use if present. The documentation sounds like there is no way. But who knows.

Comment: So just do what the guys have below.  There's some awful runtime hacking or blocks that could work... But that's just way too complicated for what you're trying to do.  Honestly, it's just not worth the effort

Comment: And that is exactly what I don´t want. I have about 120 colors in NSObject+Utilities  and I don´t know if this is a good solution.

Comment: Well, I thought of a possibility like 'count parameters'. If there are parameters I use them if not I use the constant.

Comment: Oh!  I see.  You have 120 methods, and you'd rather not balloon that to 240 methods... Perhaps a little refactoring wouldn't hurt.  Just take an alpha arg in all of them and change some method names around.  No sense over thinking it.

Comment: @CodaFi:-> Then trampoline from one to the other. What do you mean by this? I just need colors sometimes transparent and sometimes not. No trampolining at all.

Comment: So if you don't want transparency, just supply 1 as an arg.  Just because you don't want something, doesn't mean you should be implicit about it.

Comment: Yes, I was already thinking of refactoring. I was just curious if this is possible in Objective-C. I know this kind of handling from 4D.

Answer (score 4):

Write a new method with transparency parameter:

```
- (NSColor*) ccBlueLight:(CGFloat)transparency { 
   return  [self libMakeAColor    :0.000f :0.535f :1.0f :transparency];
}
```

And change the implementation of existing method to use default value.

```
- (NSColor*) ccBlueLight {
    return [self ccBlueLight:1.000f];
}
```

Note that these two are different methods. The old one's signature is not changed and there is no need to change the callers of old one.

Comment: Change the method name to `ccBlueLightWithAlpha:` and you get a +1 from me :) Personally, I prefer to be able to read the code and get an idea of what the parameter does without having to go into the method - imagining code that calls your method (i.e. `[self ccBlueLight:0.5]` and I don't know if that 0.5 is how transparent it is or how blue it is without knowing what that method looks like inside. (IMHO of course)

Comment: @deanWombourne, I agree with you that adding alpha in name is more readable but if we do not change the name then it looks more like method overloading, i.e. use `ccBlueLight` with parameter or without parameter, though it is technically not same of method overloading available in C++, Java etc. May be its just personal preference.

Comment: it's completely personal preference! However, obj-c gives you named parameters, something java and c don't have, so I personally would try to use them if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything speaking against simply adding a second method? So that one project could use the original and the other one the new method.

```
- (NSColor *) ccBlueLightWithAlpha:(NSNumber *)alpha
{
    return  [self libMakeAColor    :0.000f :0.535f :1.0f :[alpha floatValue];    
}
```

Comment: As I said in another comment,  I have about 120 colors in NSObject+Utilities. Doing what you suggest means, that I have each color twice. With transparency and without. And any time I need a new color I have it twice. No, I don´t want this.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
- (NSColor*) ccBlueLight   { 
  return  [self libMakeAColorRed:0.000f green:0.535f blue:1.0f];
}

- (NSColor*) ccBlueLightWithAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha   { 
  return  [self libMakeAColorRed:0.000f green:0.535f blue:1.0f alpha:alpha];
}
```

Comment: You don't make use of the alpha arg.